# Conflicting python versions in the same system error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python2 and several versions of python3 ( 3, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 ) installed in my computer (  16.04 ). I exclusively used to write all my codes in python2 and typing python in the command line used to launch python2.7 and python3 would launch some python3 version ( python3.5 ).

recently I had to work on a certain new project which required the use of a few libraries which are only available in python3,

I installed these libraries ( usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ )
however, when I try to import these libraries I was getting the error library not found.
I assumed this is because of the existence of multiple versions of python3.x, and deleted all the python 3.x in usr/lib/ except usr/lib/python3/ .

But now when I try to launch Python3, i'm getting the following error.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f736ebd7700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried `unset PYTHONHOME` and unset `PYTHONPATH`.
But that did not fix the problem, is there any way to fix this without installing virtual-environments ( as that is too confusing for me ).

Update : I have Python default set to be Python2.7 and it is working fine, only python3 is having problem. Also when I try to un-install Python3 by
`sudo apt-get autoremove python3` I'm getting the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packagekit-tools : Depends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed or
                             packagekit-system-interface or
                             packagekit (= 0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.5)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add only one Python application and scripts path in the environment variable.

If required, change the Python application path and the Python scripts path.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand, can you explain more please? Is it possible launch one particular version of python3 by the command python3 in terminal ?

Comment: i have two python version python 3.5 and 3.7    whe i work with python 3.7 i goto environment variable and set path as c:/Users/..../Python37-32 and c:/Users/.../Python37-32/Scripts               if i required python 3.5 i change python environment variable path as  c:/Users/..../Python35-32 and c:/Users/.../Python35-32/Scripts

Comment: wow, thats nice. I meant, right now my python paths and environments are set to use python2.7, is there any way to use python3 without disturbing that?

Comment: yes change only environment veriable all libery are saved in 2.7

Comment: Sorry, No. I'm looking for ways to parallely use Python2.7 and python3 .

Comment: to set environment veriable check this link https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: i think there is no way to use parallely two python version

Comment: I was using it that way before.